# Advanced Custom Fields Won't Display Data

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php $args=array( 'post_type'=> 'slides', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' => "date", 'order' => "desc" ); 
      $slides = get_posts( $args ); 
?>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $x=0 ;?>
    <?php foreach ( $slides as $slide ) : setup_postdata( $slide ); ?>
    <div class="item <?php echo($x === 0 ?'active':'non-active')?>" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('picture'); ?>); height:801px;">
    </div>
    <?php $x++;?>

    <?php endforeach;?>
    <php wp_reset_postdata();?>

</div>
```

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WordPress, but it is not outputting data when using the suggested code. Please see `style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('picture'); ?>`
All it outputs is blank data, I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: What do you get in `$slides` variable ?

Comment: I'm assuming that 'picture' is an image field. What do you have the Return Value set at for the field's settings? Because that setting will change how you need to output the field's data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying for more than one slide, you need to include the $slide->ID in your for each loop. Try this:

```
<?php $args=array( 'post_type'=> 'slides', 'posts_per_page' => 4,'orderby' => "date", 'order' => "desc" ); 
  $slides = get_posts( $args ); 
?>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $x=0 ;?>
    <?php foreach ( $slides as $slide ) : setup_postdata( $slide ); ?>
        <div class="item <?php echo($x === 0 ?'active':'non-active')?>" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('picture', $slide->ID); ?>); height:801px;">
        </div>
    <?php $x++;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <php wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

The best way to help you would be if you could var_dump and die on $slides or $slide and paste the response you get here. Picture may have other fields associated with it you need instead.